# I am able to see the responsive design using firefox developer tool but not able to see the same while resizing the browser

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I am developing a responsive website without bootstrap. I am able to see the desired response using Mozilla developer  tools but the same response is not functioning on re sizing the browser.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What do you see on the developer tools, and what should happen when you resize the browser? It's impossible to help with something this vague.

Comment: Tags of your question: why are you including the bootstrap tag if you aren't using it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using max-**device**-width: for your media queries. You should be using `max-width` or `min-width` if you want them to work when resizing the browser.

The former will work in Developer tools.